# can't serialize JSON swift

Tags: json, swift, serialization

I am getting {"result":"0"} string . The problems is that my serialization function cant serialize it

```
var err: NSError?
            var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as NSDictionary



if(err != nil) {
                println(err!.localizedDescription)
                let jsonStr = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                println("Error could not parse JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
            }
```

I am getting answer on console: 
Body: Optional({"result":"0"})

Error could not parse JSON: Optional({"result":"0"})

I the function cant serialize it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your variable 'data' is optional type. You have to either unwrape it. Or use ! sign. But the later is risky as it might have nil also and app will crash. So do this

```
if let dat = data
{
var err: NSError?
            var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dat, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as NSDictionary
}
```

Comment: deprecated on iOS 9/Swift 2